# How to disable VS2010 script debugging

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

How does one disable script debugging with Visual Studio 2010?  For VS2008 I used:

> reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\AD7Metrics\Engine{F200A7E7-DEA5-11D0-B854-00A0244A1DE2} /v ProgramProvider /d {4FF9DEF4-8922-4D02-9379-3FFA64D1D639} /f

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Used Shoban's answer.

You have to have the Silverlight Developer Runtime package installed for this to work.  See: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=188039 for version 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When debugging a Web App script debugging is always enabled with VS2010 and IE8 (note same issue with VS2008) eventhough script debugging has been disabled in IE8.

Note you can work around it by setting Silverlight debugging on.

[Here](http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2009/06/disabling-script-debugging-with-vs-2010.html) is how you can do it.